# install dnsmasq on fedora 19 without connection

Tags: installation, fedora, dnsmasq

I am trying to install dnsmasq-2.45.tar.gz on fedora 19 by offline
I mean I downloaded the dnsmasq-2.45.tar.gz package from the internet and i am going to install this package without any connection.
how can i do that. 
thanks for help if you can

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, What have you tried so far and what was the result of that?

Answer (score 0):

General installation guide for .tar.gz:

> tar -xzf dnsmasq-2.45.tar.gz
>
> ls
>
> cd softwarePath/
>
> ./configure
>
> make
>
> make install

---

This would be the standard idea around installing a .tar.gz file off-line, the only issue I see you facing is dependencies. If you haven't got the dependencies for dnsmasq installed prior your going to have a bad time of it all